# Update changes from multiple EditTexts to database?

Tags: android

I have dialog with ListView which is populate with ArrayList< User > users, each my_list_item contains three edit texts (name, address, city).

When I open my dialog, edit fields are populated with data. Let's say that I want to change name of first object, and city of seventh object. So, on press "Save" button want to apply changes, to save them in DB (just these two fields).

What's best way to do that, do I need to use textWatcher, OnFocusChangeListener or something else?

This dialog is used to populate and update data.

```
private void editUsers(){

        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_edit, null);
        mBuilder.setTitle("all user of this case: ");
        ListView listView = mView.findViewById(R.id.list_all_users);

        try {

            usersList = getDatabaseHelper().getmUser().queryBuilder()
            .where()
            .eq(User.ID_CASE, case.getId())
            .query();

            MyAdapterEditUser myadaper = new MyAdapterEditUser (MyActivity.this, (ArrayList<User>) userList);
            listView.setAdapter(myadaper);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                //when i click "Save" button i want to save all changes...

            }
        });

        mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

This is MyAdapterEditUser

```
public class MyAdapterEditUser extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<User> allUsersList;

    public MyAdapteAddEditStranke(Context context, ArrayList<User> allUsersList;) {
        this.context = context;
        this.allUsersList = allUsersList;;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allUsersList;.size();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetail getItem(int i) {
        return allUsersList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, null);


            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.ref = i;
        viewHolder.populateFrom(allUsersList.get(i));


        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        EditText name;
        EditText address;
        EditText city;
        int ref;

        ViewHolder(View row) {
            name = row.findViewById(R.id.my_list_et_name);
            adresa = row.findViewById(R.id.my_list_et_address);
            city = row.findViewById(R.id.my_list_et_city);
        }

        void populateFrom(User user) {

            name.setText(user.getName());
            address.setText(user.getAddress());
            mesto.setText(user.getCity());
        }

    }
}
```

List item xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <EditText android:id="@+id/my_list_et_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/my_list_et_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/my_list_et_city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no text watcher no nothing is required you are using array list why don't you update it and re Attach it to the adapter or something like that. lemme type a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

in your positive button try this! it will help!

```
 mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            //here update the array list on the items you want 


//how about checking out which edit text has changed the different values   
//than the old ones like simple if else over each edit Text you require


 try {

        updatedList = //your update query

        MyAdapterEditUser myadaper = new MyAdapterEditUser (MyActivity.this, (ArrayList<User>) updatedList);
        listView.setAdapter(myadaper);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        }
    });
```

Comment: But how do I know which edit text is changed? I want to update only objects whose values are changed! For example, name of city of third object in listview.